# How to find a php_mongo.dll that will work with my version?

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to use MongoDB with PHP Version 5.6.3. I am running XAMPP with these versions:

- API : Apache 2.0 Handler
- Compiler :    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
- Architecture : x86Handler

When I run XAMPP server there's a warning sign next to libsasl.dll is missing from your computer. I'm not getting which php_mongo.dll would work with my version?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Does XAMPP come with Mongo support enabled?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 professional.and Mongo support not enabled

Comment: @saveATcode: thanks for wanting to improve the readability of the question. However I think we have a consensus here that code formatting (backticks) is not appropriate as a general highlighter - it is best reserving that for code or console i/o. If you encounter names of languages or technologies, they just become proper nouns in English, so capitalisation is generally sufficient.

Comment: @user4404410: did you resolve this question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can download Mongo extensions [from PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo). If you are in doubt which version to go for, select the latest stable, which at the time of writing [is 1.5.8](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.8/windows).

This will save you the trouble of compiling your own on Windows, which is usually a great deal harder than on *nix-like systems.